# How can Cassandra tuned to be CA in CAP theorem?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I know The CAP theorem:

Consistency (all nodes see the same data at the same time)

Availability (a guarantee that every request receives a response about whether it was successful or failed)

Partition tolerance (the system continues to operate despite arbitrary message loss or failure of part of the system)

Cassandra is typically classified as an AP system, I heard yes it can turned to CA, but I didn't find the documentation. 
How to use CA Cassandra ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the 'P' in CAP is what NoSQL technologies were built to solve for.  This is usually accomplished by spreading data horizontally across multiple instances.

Therefore, if you wanted Cassandra to run in a "CA" CAP configuration, running it as a single node cluster would be a good first step.

> I heard yes it can turned to CA, but I didn't find the documentation.

After re-reading this, it's possible that you may have confused "CA" with "CP."

It is possible to run Cassandra as a "CP" database, or at least tune it to *behave* more in that regard.  The way to go about this, would be to set queries on the application side to use the higher levels of consistency, like [LOCAL_]QUORUM, EACH_QUORUM, or even ALL.  Consistency could be tuned even higher, by increasing the replication factor (RF) in each keyspace definition.  Setting RF equal to number of nodes and querying at ALL consistency would be about as high as it could be tuned to be consistent.

However, I feel compelled to mention at what a terrible, terrible idea this all is.  Cassandra was *engineered* to be "AP."  Fighting that intrinsic design is a fool's errand.  I've always said, nobody wins when you try to out-Cassandra Cassandra.

If you're employing engineering time to make a datastore function in ways that are contrary to its design, then a different datastore (one you don't have to work *against*) might be the better choice.